# How to extract binary file content from HTTP body of post request?

Tags: c++, http, webserver, browser, binaryfiles

Currently, I try to implement one simple web server with C++ under windows. To support file upload, `POST` is implemented in my codes.

Now, when one binary file is uploaded through IE, two extra characters `0D` and `0A` is added into the end of file.

The file content before uploading

[image]

The file content after uploading

[image]

Here are some codes pieces

```
// receive data from http socket
char* orig_buf = buf;
while ( (cnt=recv(m_hSocket, buf, 1, 0)) > 0)
{
    if(*buf++ == '\n')
    {
        *buf = '\0';
        buflen = buf - orig_buf;
        return orig_buf;
    }
}

// save buffer to binary file
std::ofstream ofs(szFilename, std::ofstream::out | std::ofstream::trunc | std::ofstream::binary);
ofs.write(buf, buflen);
```

Through [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler), we find the `0D 0A` is added by web browser.

[image]

In this [specs](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616), we know the file line ending should be added into before `Boundary`. However, the first question: **what if there is no 0D 0A between file content and Boundary?** Because if the content of binary file including `0D 0A`, it is hard to distinguish whether `0D 0A` is belong to the binary file or not.

Per @CodeCaster, add header of post message here

[image]

Question 2: **How to extract binary file content from http body?**

- By `Content-Length`? or By `Boundary`? with eliminating `0D 0A`.

Comment: `0D 0A` is a typical windows format line ending. Did you accidentially insert on at the end after download?

Comment: No, when I debug it in the function `recv`, `0D 0A` is already in the data buffer, when receiving the data from socket.

Comment: Is `Content-Length` available in the POST header? If yes, you should only accept as many bytes as specified in the header.

Comment: @zangw Then it looks more of a problem of the server side.

Comment: The `content-Length` is the length of the http body, including file content, boundary, content-disposition, and so on

Comment: Can you show the relevant request headers, like `Content-type`?

Answer (score 0):

> what if there is no 0D 0A between file content and Boundary? Because if the content of binary file including 0D 0A, it is hard to distinguish whether 0D 0A is belong to the binary file or not.

The user agent has to make sure to pick a boundary that isn't present in the payload.